# How to arrange Icon behind the others (mui)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using [material-ui](https://mui.com/) for react.

I have the following code:

```
<Autocomplete
    multiple
    options={['One','Two','Three']}
    value={value}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option}
    filterSelectedOptions
    renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
            {...params}
            InputProps={{
                ...params.InputProps,
                endAdornment: (
                    <>
                        {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
                        <IconButton color="primary"
                                    edge="start" aria-label="help">
                            <HelpOutlineIcon/>
                        </IconButton>
                    </>
                ),
            }}
            color="primary"
            label="Some label"
        />
    )}
/>
```

Now I have the problem that my `IconHelpButton` is always before the arrow button. How can I set the `IconHelpButton` **behind** the arrow button?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the **Autocomplete component** inside a **div** with a `display: "flex"` , and add your icon outside the  **TextField** component.  and add `sx={{ width: 300 }}` to the Autocomplete .
**like this  :**

```
<div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <Autocomplete
        sx={{ width: 300 }}
        multiple
        options={["One", "Two", "Three"]}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option}
        filterSelectedOptions
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            InputProps={{
              ...params.InputProps
            }}
            color="primary"
            label="Some label"
          />
        )}
      />
      <IconButton color="primary" aria-label="help">
        <HelpOutlineIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </div>
```

this is a demo in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/combobox-material-demo-forked-3zy4qm?file=/demo.js)  .

Comment: Thx for the option, but I need it inside the textfield component